# api working in postman but not in angularjs code

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to insert data using api which is in python. The api is working fine when i am checking it in postman but when i am trying to insert the data through my code, it is giving me 400 error "Bad Request". I also checked similar queries but none of them helped. I am really stuck. Any help would be great. Thanks in advance.

```
 $scope.insert=function(data){  
    $scope.activeData= angular.copy(data);  
    if(($scope.id || $scope.activeData.name || $scope.activeData.url || 
    $scope.activeData.phone)== null){
      alert("Please fill all fields");
    }  
    else{
    var config = {
            headers : {

                'cache-control' : 'no-cache',
                'content-type' : 'undefined'
            }
    }
    var formData={
                'id':$scope.activeData.id,
                'name':$scope.activeData.name,
                'url':$scope.activeData.url,
                'phone':$scope.activeData.phone,

    };

    $http.post("http://myurl/data/add", 
    {result:formData},config)
    .then(function successCallback(response) {
    console.log(response);
    alert("Data Inserted Successfully");
    $state.transitionTo($state.current, $stateParams, {
    reload: true,
    inherit: false,
    notify: true
    });
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'http://myurl/data/add',
            data: formData.join('&')
        }).success(function(data) {
            alert("Data Inserted Successfully");
      });

Comment: is there any error in console like CORS?

Comment: Remove , after 'phone':$scope.activeData.phone,

Comment: @slacker it is giving me formData.join is not a function error.

Comment: @GauravSrivastava no there is no CORS error in console.

Comment: @Vivz that didn't make any difference. still not working

Comment: Try to stringify your `formData`