# similar post req giving response in postman but not on angular $http.post

Tags: angularjs, http, post, http-headers

There is post request to get token for user . I have used angular $http.post method In my browser  network window its not giving me response but when i try this in postman it gives me response here is screen shot attached 
please help
[image: first image]

[image: reponse image]

[image: postman image]

```
this.login = function (loginData) {

        var data = "grant_type=password&username=" + loginData.userName + "&password=" + loginData.password;

        //if (loginData.rememberMe) {
        data = data + "&client_id=" + constants.AUTHSETTINGS.CLIENT_ID;
        //}
        debugger;
        console.log(data)

        var deferred = $q.defer();
        $http.post(api_url + '/token', data, { 
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
         })
        .then
        (function (response) {
            if (loginData.rememberMe) {
                localStorageService.set('authorizationData', { token: response.data.access_token, userName: loginData.userName, refreshToken: response.data.refresh_token, useRefreshTokens: true });
            }
            else {
                localStorageService.set('authorizationData', { token: response.data.access_token, userName: loginData.userName, refreshToken: "", useRefreshTokens: false });
            }
            console.log('---auth servcie')
            console.log(response)
            authentication.isAuth = true;
            authentication.userName = loginData.userName;
            authentication.useRefreshTokens = loginData.rememberMe;

            deferred.resolve(response);
        }
        ,function (err, status) {
                console.log('auth error -- here ')
                console.log(err)
                console.log(status)
                deferred.reject(err);
                //deferred.resolve(err);
            });


        return deferred.promise;
    };
```

raw data
    var data = "grant_type=password&username=asad@gmail.com&password=1234&client_id=angularjs

Comment: why negative vote ?

Comment: I believe its because you didnt include the js part of the `$http.post` so people cannot really help you

Comment: added @JaqenH'ghar

Comment: can you give answer @JaqenH'ghar

Comment: Alright its not my downvote but I upvoted you anyway your question is legit. Well not sure about the answer 100% because never tried it before but it looks as you should encode your data.. see this [so link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24710503/how-do-i-post-urlencoded-form-data-with-http) good luck

Comment: thank you for ur help this looks like my problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45431372/api-working-in-postman-but-not-in-angularjs-code

Comment: I have seen ur link my data is already in that format :(

Comment: The question is off-topic because there's not enough data. This problem totally depends on the backend and can't be replicated by readers. You're the only person who can debug what's wrong. You've attached request data for $http (without the most important piece, which is `data`) but not for Postman. Compare raw requests line by line for both cases and figure out the difference.

Comment: hI @estus loginData is only contain user name and password its obvious it is making query string here `var data = "grant_type=password&username=" + loginData.userName + "&password=" + loginData.password;`

Comment: I have posted whole screen for postman you can see the www from encoded data

Comment: here is duplicate question but not answered  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45431372/api-working-in-postman-but-not-in-angularjs-code

Comment: Please, show *raw POST request with request payload* for both cases. A screenshot with filled form in Postman doesn't count, it doesn't contain headers, see http://blog.getpostman.com/2015/06/13/debugging-postman-requests/. You'll likely be able to tell what's wrong by yourself after doing that. The said question is not answered because it's also an offtopic that cannot gain a quality answer.

Comment: raw data is added Header is shown in my js code ` headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }`

Comment: and postman screen shot is shown u can see header there

Comment: showing on postman inspecting window and on mozila firefix